# Hide Quick Action Button on Salesforce Mobile App based on Condition

Tags: lightning-quickaction, salesforce-mobile-app, highlights-panel

I have created one 'create record' action on an opportunity. This action is related to its child object. Now I want to show or hide this button based on the conditions. If productcount (which is a formula field that contains the number of products count related to that opportunity) contains values greater than 0, then only the user can create a record of the child object. Otherwise, the button should be hidden, or there should be a popup on button click so that the user cannot create a record. All this functionality I have achieved using highlight panel dynamic actions, but it is not working for the mobile Salesforce app.
So can someone please help me with this?

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

for Custom objects alone, you will get the Dynamic Actions on the Lightning App builder for Mobile App, for Standard objects may need to use the Compact Layout and the Page layout's actions available for Mobile App.

You need to have a record type associated with the profile and your app page rendering for both desktop / phone as form factor when you activate the page, but make sure that the page layout for the record type should contain those Action buttons for it to appear on Mobile App.

Dynamic rendering would be not possible to achieve for your requirement, you can add an alert when your mobile Action on the page layout is exposed, if suppose if you add a LWC component with `lightning-quick-action-panel` then you can set your conditions on your JS and display on your Markup.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I have raised a case for this to the salesforce support. As per they, we do not have such a functionality to hide this create record button on mobile app till now. So may be in the next release they will update this. Thank you,